# I will be/am interested to see

Tags: modal-verbs, politeness, future-constructions

1. I **will be** interested to see whether there’s a white Christmas in London tomorrow.
2. I **am** interested to see whether there’s a white Christmas in London tomorrow.

What is the difference between (1) and (2)? Is the speaker of (1) indirectly saying that they're actually not interested?

Comment: The two tenses are interchangeable and mean exactly the same thing in many contexts. Unless pronounced or emphasised differently, for example, **I am going to town tomorrow** and **I will be going to town tomorrow** are both saying that the speaker will be going to town the following day.

Comment: Disagree @MelonDusk. Both sentences refer to the speaker's current curiosity about tomorrow's weather. It's an interesting question because you'd expect there to be a difference due to the grammar, but there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

(2) suggests the speaker is about to look up a weather forecast. If he's interested NOW, he is about to investigate.

In everyday speech it's quite interchangable though.